# How many distinct pair of boxes of exact size = 2 can I form from $n$ distinct elements?

Tags: combinatorics

Drawing some diagrams and pyramids (and to better explain the problem), I obtained the following results:

- For the minimum case of 4 distinct balls $\lbrace1,2,3,4\rbrace$, there are 3 possible cases.

  $\lbrace 12|34, 13|24, 14|23 \rbrace$
- For 5 distinct balls $\lbrace 1,2,3,4,5 \rbrace$, there are 15 cases.

  $\lbrace 12|34, 13|24, 14|23, 12|35, 13|25, 15|23, 12|54, 15|24, 14|25, 15|34, 13|54, 14|53, 25|34, 35|24, 45|23 \rbrace$
- And for 6 distinct balls $\lbrace 1,2,3,4,5,6 \rbrace $, I manually counted 45 cases.

As you may noticed, no configuration of boxes and no element should be repeated.

What is the combinatorial function (depending on the $n$ number of distinct balls) that models this problem? I would appreciate any kind of help.

**EDIT 1:** edited title, I would like to count the possible configurations of **pair of boxes**

**EDIT 2:** updated counting result for the case $n=6$.

Comment: To be clear, for the 6 ball case, are you having two sets of two?  Or three sets of two?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. I edited the statement. I would like to count how many possible **pairs** of boxes (each of size 2) can I form from $n$ distinct elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Revised in response to the clarification.**

There are $\binom{n}2$ different pairs. Once we’ve chosen one of them, there are $\binom{n-2}2$ ways to choose a pair from the remaining $n-2$ balls, so there are $\binom{n}2\binom{n-2}2$ **ordered** pairs of boxes with disjoint contents. Since we want **unordered** pairs of boxes, this has to be divided by $2$: there are

$$\frac12\binom{n}2\binom{n-2}2=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{8}$$

possible pairs of boxes with disjoint contents.

Comment: @JMoravitz: No, and on further thought I see at least one thing wrong with it: at the very least I should be dividing by $2^m$.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your quick answer, I really appreciate it. It's amazing how your result $\frac{n!}{2^m \lfloor n/2 \rfloor !}$ works for $n=4$ and $n=5$. My complication is with $n=6$. I counted the possible combinations again (by hand), and now I obtain a value of 44 possible combinations, which is different from the value obtained by replacing $n=6$ and $m=3$ into your formula. Probably I'm counting wrong...

Comment: @Pskdos: You’re welcome. I get $12|34|56$, $12|35|46$, $12|36|45$, $13|24|56$, $13|25|46$, $13|26|45$, $14|23|56$, $14|25|36$, $14|26|35$, $15|23|46$, $15|25|36$, $15|26|34$, $16|23|45$, $16|24|35$, and $16|25|34$.

Comment: Thanks again. Now I see the origin of our discrepancy. This is probably because I explained myself poorly. I want to count how many **pair** of boxes I can count. Here I attach a Google Spreadsheet of [my counting](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-IIfzB3n-N8ZQZ_YyY9ypfydfBdRW2a1rTBdBe0ADSY/edit?usp=sharing). (It was 45 in the end!) If you happen to know how to model these combinations, I would be even more grateful.

Comment: @Pskdos: Ah, okay; it’ll take me a few minutes to revise my answer.

Comment: Now that expression $\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{8}$ looks familiar... Looking back at my notes, trying to solve this, I previously obtained: $3 \binom{n}{4}$, which gives the same result that you obtained in your final edit. Your thinking confirms it and now I can safely continue my work. Thank you very much!! Very clear explanation.

Comment: @Pskdos: You’re very welcome! $3\binom{n}4$ can be analyzed as $\frac12\binom{n}4\binom42$: first choose $4$ balls in $\binom{n}4$ ways, then choose $2$ of them for one box in $\binom42$ ways, putting the other $2$ in the other box, and then divide by $2$ because you’d have got the same pair of boxes had you chosen the other pair first.

Answer (score 0):

So for an even number of items $N=2m$ labelled $1..N$, you can arrange them in $N!$ different orders. By putting a division after every second object you can divide the set into pairs. So you have $N!$ sets of $N/2$ ordered pairs.

Each pair $(p,q)$ will be such that $P>q$ or $p<q$. Discard any sets with any $p<q$ pair, which leaves you with $N!/2^{(N/2)}$ sets of pairs.

Now look at neighboring pairs and discard all sets in which a following pair is 'larger' than a proceeding pair (i..e if the set contains $...(p,q),...(r,s)...$ then $p>r$). This will reduce your set s by a factor of $(N/2)!)$ to $N!/(2^{(N/2)}(N/2)!)$ So you now have that many ordered sets of N/2 ordered pairs.

Finally, from your N/2 pairs pick any first pair, then any second pair, and divide by 2. So you finally have $N!/(2^{(N/2)}(N/2)!)*(N/2)*(N/2-1)/2$ distinct pairs of pairs. This can be simplified to $N!/(2^{(N/2+1)}(N/2-2)!)$, and for N=6 confirms there should be $6!/(2^{6/3}.(6/3-2)!)=45$ pairs of pairs (as you calculated).